# fixed div on the right in bootstrap grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have two div elements in webpage. Left and right. As per requirement, right div must be fixed but responsive and left to float normally. This is in html page with background and with padding on both left and right sides.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col-lg-7 ">
        <div class="row">

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 fixed">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style Sheet is

.fixed { position:fixed;  }

When i try use above code, fixed div is overlapped on the left div.

I added col-lg-7 offset to right side div.

class="col-lg-5 fixed col-lg-7-offset"

The div is aligned to right but its outside the div wrapper. I mean the div is floating to main div with background.

How can i fix the div to right side within wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove the offset because it's offsetting it towards the other div.

Second, you need not use a fixed positioning with your current setup because under certain screen resolutions that fixed position stays whereas the non-fixed position will move around, and in this case will be overlapped by the fixed div.

Further, your setup is not really ideal, you should have the rows outside of the columns.

Example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7 ">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 fixed ">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But by doing this you now have 5 columns in the first row that should be accompanied with the other 7 columns, and same thing on the second row. This empty space can cause you problems.

Comment: But i need both the divs side by side

Comment: The content must be displayed side by side and right side div must be fixed. Is there another way to solve the issue i got.